# User ID validation in python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

```py
def validate_user():
    """ validate the users ID """

    try:
        user_id = int(input('\n      Enter a customer id <Example 1 for user_id 1>: '))

        if user_id > 0 or user_id < 3:
            print("\n  Apologies, that's not a valid customer number, please try again...\n")
        
        return user_id   

    except ValueError:
        print("\n  Hmm thats an invalid number, please try again...\n")

        return validate_user()
```

I'm looking to get the user to input a correct value between 1-3 and only when inserting the correct ID will it give the account information. However, when a user puts in the incorrect User ID like 4 I want the program to give them a chance to retry instead of the program closing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```py
def validate_user():
    """Validate an user ID"""

    while True:
        try:
            ans = int(input("\n\tEnter a customer ID (e.g., insert '1' for 'user_id 1'); it must be in range [1, 3]: "))
            if ans <= 0 or ans > 3:
                print(f"\n\tApologies '{ans}' is not in the allowed [1, 3] range, please try again...\n")
                continue
            return ans
        except ValueError:
            print("\n\tHmm that's an invalid number, please try again...\n")
```

In this implementation, you ask the user for a valid ID, and the `while` loop keeps going until the user inserts a valid number. Changing the condition for the `while`, you can set a maximum number of attempts.